# Referencing Worksheets for IF MATCH AND analysis

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with the following columns:

Worksheet 1: Company Records

```
Column A= Company ID#
Column B= Item #
Column C= Total Qty
Column D= Total Revenue
```

Worksheet 2: Reporting

```
Column A= Company ID#
Column B= Item #
Column C= Reported Qty
Column D= Reported Revenue
```

I'm trying to create a formula that will analyze the following: 
 If the Company ID# from worksheet 1 matches one from Column A in Worksheet 2 AND Item # from Worksheet 1 matches one from Column B in Worksheet 2, then display The Reported Qty from Worksheet 2 into Total Qty in Worksheet 1.

I will need the same formula to reference the revenue (if company id matches and item number matches, reference reported revenue into Column D of Worksheet 1). The rows do not match so I'm assuming that an IF/INDEX formula would be best to use or should I be using LOOKUP or MATCH? I've tried several times, but cannot seem to correctly enter a formula that has two conditions.

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX('Worksheet2'!A4:A128, MATCH('Worksheet2!A4, 'Worksheet1'!A9:A743,0)))
```

This seems to be over my head. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you can use this Array formula, it would go into C2 on Worksheet1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Worksheet2'!C$4:C$128,MATCH($A2 & "|" & $B2,'Worksheet2'!$A$4:$A$128 & "|" & 'Worksheet2'!$B$4:$B$128,0)),"")
```

***Being an Array Formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode, instead of Enter or tab***.  If you entered it properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then you can drag over one column and down as far as needed.

Comment: **BINGO!** Thank you so much!